# Excel VSTO call results different between v2003 and v2007 - why?

Tags: c#, vsto, excel-2007

I have this piece of c# code in my Excel 2003 add-in:

```
var leafPoint = m_worksheet.Shapes.Item("aPoint").Duplicate();

leafPoint.Name = "Shape" + (m_shapesNameIndex++).ToString();
leafPoint.OnAction = m_worksheet.CodeName + ".PointClicked";
leafPoint.AlternativeText = 

string.Format("Correlation Value: {0}",     
    item.PointData.Correlation.ToString("0.0000;-0.0000"));

leafPoint.Top = item.LeftChildNode.Top + 
    ((item.RightChildNode.Top - item.LeftChildNode.Top) / 2) + 
    (leafPoint.Height / 2);
```

When I run it in Excel 2003, it works perfectly.  However, when I run it in Excel 2007, the shape's Top value is off... It always ends up a few pixels above the intended location!

When I looked at the logs, in Excel 2003 the shapes were consistently placed in the correct position, but in Excel 2007, when the code attempts to place the shape's Top position, Excel 2007 seems to be overriding the value for some reason (I think).

For instance, in one case the `leafPoint.Top` value resolved to `206.25`.  In Excel 2003, that was indeed the result.  However, in Excel 2007, this value ends up becoming `204.2954`...

Does anyone have some insight into this issue?

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but this article discusses some of the changes between 2003 and 2007, and one of the areas which has changed is shapes. In particular, it seems that shapes created through 2003 and 2007 are not necessarily the same. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179188(office.12).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  Based on this link [Excel 2007 Service Pack 2 – the official fix list](http://news.office-watch.com/t/n.aspx?a=849), it mentions among the fixed bugs:

> The value of the Top property of the
>   Line object is affected by Zoom level.
>   This leads to incorrect placement of
>   line shapes when this value is set
>   programmatically to lines on a sheet
>   that is zoomed to anything other than
>   100%.

I figured if the Line object was affected, possibly could there have been a problem with the Shape object as well?

So I checked my template, and indeed, it was set to 80%.  (Line objects work fine, by the way, since my Excel version has SP2 installed).  As soon as I set the zoom level to 100%, the shape objects suddenly rendered to the position they were expected to.

*Another note:* this problem only occurs **during** rendering.  Once all the shapes have been drawn, I can set the zoom level to whatever I want, and the shapes position themselves properly.

*Conclusion:*  whenever drawing shapes in Excel, **always** set the zoom level to 100%.  After all the drawing is done, you can set the zoom level back to the original desired zoom.

Answer (score 0):

It's the `.Duplicate` function that does this. It doesn't duplicate the same `.Top` or `.Left`. My guess is the change is a result from customer feedback about not being able to find their duplicated shapes (you can duplicate manually as well be selecting the shape and click <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>.

You can just sent those to the original shape's `.Top` and`.Left`. . Here's an example in VBA:

```
Sub AddShapeAndDuplicate()
    Dim sh As Shape
    Set mysheet = Worksheets(1)
    With mysheet.Shapes
    Set sh = .AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, 144, 144, 72, 72)
        With sh
            .Name = "Red Square"
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    End With

    Dim sh2 As Shape
    Set sh2 = sh.Duplicate
    With sh2
        .Top = sh.Top
        .Left = sh.Left
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: but I **am** setting the Top manually...! On the last line I'm setting the Top property...

Comment: That's a POCO, not a shape, no.

Comment: POCO = "Plain Old CLR Object"; an item is one of the objects he created for his application, not a native Excel object.